# Center one element relatively to another but never off the screen

Tags: css

Imagine we you have two elements. One of the is a container and another is absolutely positioned widget (like a tooltip, for instance). I centre one below another using this CSS code:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}
.widget {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 50%;
}
```

`.container` can be anywhere on the page and `[************]` represents the widget. Above CSS results in this:

```
|    [.container]   |
|   [************]  |
```

However, there's a problem when `.container` is close to the screen edge, because then part of the widget is positioned off the screen and not visible:

```
|[.container]       |
|************]      |
```

My question is: Is there any clever way to make sure this element is never positioned off the screen **withouth using JavaScript**? I'm supporting only modern browsers, using `calc` or `vw` is fine. I'm free to modify both HTML and CSS. **The widget has fixed width.**

Expected result in this case:

```
|[.container]       |
|[************]     |
```

Fiddle with the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/5xdhhh8f/1/

Comment: Can you create a fiddle of what you have so far?

Comment: if the widget has a fixed width, you could have a second wrapper around the container with the width of the container+widget and that way make sure it has always enough space. the drawback is that in case the widget should have floated over other elements in the page, it wont be possible. this would also ensure that in case the container is at the bottom of the page, the widget wont hide out of the page either.. you could use padding for the container if you dont wish to add new elements

Comment: I don't think it's possible. If [minmax()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax) were supported it could be done. At the moment however I don't see a way.

Comment: i agree with you, unless you can have some assumptions about the fixed width of the widget..

Comment: @IvanModric added fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5xdhhh8f/1/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only centering horizontally, you can use the following to center and contain the elements.

```css
.container{
  text-align:center;
 }

.widget{
  display:table;
  margin:0 auto;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  SOME TEXT
  <div class="widget">SOME WIDGET</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This won't work if the width of `widget` is larger than the width of `container`, which is the case (see fiddle attached to the original post).

Comment: You might be able to put a `max-width` property on the widget as 100%. Can't try right now.